# numpy.einsum with ellipses of different dimensionality

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I often find that I'd like like to do an operation between the last few dimensions of two arrays, where the first dimensions don't necessarily match. As an example I'd like to do something like:

```
a = np.random.randn(10, 10, 3, 3)
b = np.random.randn(5, 3)
c = np.einsum('...ij, ,,,j -> ...,,,i', a, b)
```

and the result should satisfy `c.shape = (10, 10, 5, 3)` and `c[i, j, k] = a[i, j] @ b[k]`. Is there a way to achieve this with the existing interface?

Comment: What's with all those commas?

Comment: `np.einsum('...ij,kj->...ki', a, b)`, with one more distinguishable axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up getting around the issue with the following helper function

```
def batch_matvec(A, b):
    product = np.einsum('...ij, ...kj->...ki', A, b.reshape(-1, b.shape[-1]))
    return product.reshape((*A.shape[:-2], *b.shape[:-1], -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [82]: c = np.einsum('...ij,...j->...i', a, b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [82], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 c = np.einsum('...ij,...j->...i', a, b)

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in einsum(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\einsumfunc.py:1359, in einsum(out, optimize, *operands, **kwargs)
   1357     if specified_out:
   1358         kwargs['out'] = out
-> 1359     return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
   1361 # Check the kwargs to avoid a more cryptic error later, without having to
   1362 # repeat default values here
   1363 valid_einsum_kwargs = ['dtype', 'order', 'casting']

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes 
[original->remapped]: (10,10,3,3)->(10,10,3,3) (5,3)->(5,newaxis,3)
```

So it's trying to use `broadcasting` to match dimensions.

Let's make `a` (10,10,1,3,3) shape.  That way the (10,10,1) part broadcasts with the (5,) of `b`:

```
In [83]: c = np.einsum('...ij,...j->...i', a[:,:,None], b)
In [84]: c.shape
Out[84]: (10, 10, 5, 3)
```

Comment: while this works in this specific case when a.ndim == 4 and b.dim == 2, but I was looking for something that can handle any dimensionality of a and b as long as the final dimensions match. See my answer